# 2 start and 2 end dates difference. sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 dates. For example.

2 start dates and 2 end dates, like:

```
Start_Date_HE 2013-08-15 01:24:00.000   

End_Date_HE 2013-08-15 02:09:00.000
```

and

```
Start_Date_Lunch    
2013-08-14 20:40:00.000 

End_Date_Luch
2013-08-14 21:40:00.000
```

I wanna know hou many minutes i have between these dates.

In this sample is might be 0. because 20:40 until 21:40 is not between 01:24 until 02:09

Comment: You can only have an interval between two datetimes and there are 4 from which to choose.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean please?

Comment: As I understand question was about getting a intersecting between two timespans. How much minutes of timespan(startLunch to endLunch) are inside of timespan(startHE to endHE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version, it seems as a mess, but work for your values:

```
SELECT l.ID AS LunchID
, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi,
    CASE WHEN l.StartDate BETWEEN h.StartDate AND h.EndDate THEN l.StartDate ELSE
        (CASE WHEN l.StartDate < h.StartDate THEN h.StartDate ELSE NULL END) END,
    CASE WHEN l.EndDate BETWEEN h.StartDate AND h.EndDate THEN l.EndDate ELSE
        (CASE WHEN l.EndDate > h.EndDate THEN h.EndDate ELSE NULL END) END),
    0) AS Result
FROM Lunch l
LEFT JOIN HE h ON h.ID = 1
```

Or if you going to use this more then in one query, may be will be better create a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetBetweenMinutes(
    @HStart DATETIME,
    @HEnd DATETIME,
    @LStart DATETIME,
    @LEnd DATETIME)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DiffStart DATETIME
    DECLARE @DiffEnd DATETIME

    IF (@LStart BETWEEN @HStart AND @HEnd)
        SET @DiffStart = @LStart
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF (@LStart < @HStart)
                SET @DiffStart = @HStart
            ELSE
                SET @DiffStart = NULL
        END

    IF (@LEnd BETWEEN @HStart AND @HEnd)
        SET @DiffEnd = @LEnd
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        IF (@LEnd > @HEnd)
            SET @DiffEnd = @HEnd
        ELSE
            SET @DiffEnd = NULL
        END

    RETURN ISNULL(DATEDIFF(mi,@DiffStart,@DiffEnd),0)
END;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54a7e/2) with sample of data

Comment: NICE SOLUTION. 

IT WORKS AMAZING. THAT'S EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED TO DO.

I WILL SHARE THE SOLUTION I DID TOO BUT, I CAN NOT INSERT RIGHT NOW BECAUSE I NEED TO WAIT. BUT THANKS ANYWAY

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,End_Date_HE,Start_Date_HE) AS DiffDate

SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,End_Date_Luch,Start_Date_Lunch ) AS DiffDate
```

Comment: No. ... actually I want. for example:

how many minutes i have between the date 

Start_Date_HE 2013-08-15 01:24:00.000   

End_Date_HE 2013-08-15 02:09:00.000

according to the date 

Start_Date_Lunch    
2013-08-14 20:40:00.000 

End_Date_Luch
2013-08-14 21:40:00.000

In this case it is 0.

but let's say it is:
Start_Date_Lunch    
2013-08-15 01:40:00.000 

End_Date_Luch
2013-08-15 02:09:00.000

I will have 29 minutes.